# Question about the proof of "If $H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, then $|H|=p^n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

**Definition.** A subgroup $P$ of a group $G$ is said to be a *Sylow $p$-subgroup* ($p$ prime) if $P$ is a maximal $p$-subgroup of $G$.

**Theorem.** Let $|G|=p^{n}m$ with $p$ prime, $n\ge 1$ and $\gcd(p, m)=1$. Let $H$ be a $p$-subgroup of $G$. Then $H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ iff $|H|=p^{n}$.

I have a problem in the 'if' part of the proof, which goes as follows:

**Proof.** ($\implies$)  Let $H$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup and $|H|=p^{i}$, where $1\le i < n$. Then (by Sylow's first theorem$^1$) there exists $H'\le G$ such that $|H'|=p^{i+1}$ and $H \trianglelefteq H'$. Because $H$ is a maximal $p$-subgroup of $G$, it must be that $H=H'$, which is clearly not possible since $|H|\neq |H'|$. We thus have a contradiction and so $|H|=p^{n}$.

**Question.** Why does maximality imply that $H=H'$, and not $H'=G$?

---

$^1$**Theorem**   Let $G$ be a group of order $p^{n}m$, with $n\ge 1$, $p$ prime, and $\gcd(p, m)=1$. Then,

(1) $G$ contains a subgroup of order $p^{i}$ for each $1\le i\le n$, and

(2) if $H\le G$ is such that $|H|=p^{i}$, where $1\le i < n$, then there exists some $H'\le G$ such that $|H'|=p^{i+1}$ and $H \trianglelefteq H'$.

Comment: I wouldn't use the notation $H'$ here; that is standard notation for the commutator subgroup of $H$.

Comment: Because the definition refers to maximality among $p$-subgroups, and $G$ is not a $p$-subgroup of itself.

Comment: @RobertShore But $G$ could be a $p$-group, in which case it would be a $p$-subgroup of itself. When we say that $G$ is a maximal $p$-subgroup of $G$, we are not excluding the possibility that $H=G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, I had forgotten that we are not assuming $m>1$. So the possibility of $G$ being a $p$-subgroup of itself persists. Reading closely the definition from the book I'm following (Algebra by Hungerford), the definition of a maximal $p$-subgroup is give as: $P$ is a $p$-subgroup and if $H$ is another $p$-group such that $P\le H\le G$ then $P=H$. The possibility that $H=G$ is not mentioned.

Comment: @RobertShore When $m=1$, $G$ itself is a $p$-group. The answer should depend on whether the $p$-subgroup is a proper subgroup. I think different researchers may have different definitions. If this concept is clarified in OP, then everything is clear.

Comment: @J.Doe: It is also not excluded. What the definition says is that $P$ is not *properly contained* in any $p$-subgroup of $G$. If $G$ happens to be a $p$-group, then this also requires $P=G$. I think you are getting confused with the definition of “maximal subgroup” ($M$ is a maximal subgroup if $M\lt G$ and $M\leq H\leq G$ implies $M=H$ or $H=G$). Note that there is no requirement that the maximal $p$-subgroup be *proper*: it is maximal among all $p$-subgroups (whereas a “maximal subgroup” is maximal among *proper* subgroups).

Comment: @ZongxiangYi I don't agree with "different researchers may have different definitions". Of course that is true as a general statement but not in this context. I have never heard anyone claim that the Sylow $2$-subgroups of a group of order $4$ are its subgroups of order $2$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Yes I was thoroughly confused. However, after reading your and Derek Holt's comments, the definitions are clear. However, I'm not sure how to get the proof out of the ditch still. If I want to discuss the possibility $H'=G$ in the proof, how should I go about doing that?

Comment: @J.Doe: There is no need to. You know $H’$ is a $p$-subgroup (whether it equals $G$ or not). You know $H$ is a maximal $p$-subgroup. You know $H\leq H’$. That alone tells you $H=H’$.  There is no “$H’=G$” clause because you aren’t talking about “maximal subgroups”, you are talking about *maximal-$p$-subgroups*.

Comment: @J.Doe The real issue is laziness. When we talk about “maximal subgroup”, we should *really* be saying “maximal proper subgroup”, but nobody wants to keep saying “proper” all the time, so we elide the properness. But here, when talking about maximal $p$-subgroup, we are *not* restricted to proper subgroups. This leads to confusion because the terms sound similar. If we went around saying “maximal proper subgroup” all the time, then the definition could be: “a proper subgroup $H$ is a maximal proper subgroup if whenever $H’$ is a proper subgroup and $H\leq H’$, then $H=H’$”.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, one last question: does the definition of 'proper subgroup' include the possibility that $H=\emptyset$, since it is a proper subset also? What I'm trying to ask is that is there a difference between non-trivial and proper?

Comment: @J.Doe: A proper subgroup is a subgroup that is properly contained in the group. The empty set is not a subgroup (it is not a group: it does not contain the identity), so it cannot be a proper subgroup. A nontrivial subgroup is a subgroup that is not equal to $\{e\}$. A proper subgroup is a subgroup that is not equal to the whole group.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Sorry, I meant to write $\{e\}$. Atleast, that's what I was thinking about. However, I get the distinction now. TYSM.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, after re-reading your second comment, the choice of wording seems odd. You wrote that there is no $H'=G$ clause because we aren't talking about maximal subgroups.  Don't you mean "if we were talking about maximal subgroups"? I think the case $H'=G$ would definitely need to be discussed here. Indeed, if $H'=G$, then $G$ is a $p$-group and that would be a contradiction to the assumption that $H$ is a maximal $p$-subgroup.

Comment: @J.Doe: There is no need to consider the $H’=G$ case *separately*. There is nothing to be gained by considering that case, there is no difference between the situation where $G$ is a $p$-group and the situation where $G$ is not a $p$-group. You do *not* need to consider separately anything about whether $H’$ equals $G$ or not. There is no special clause in the definition of “maximal $p$-subgroup” for the case where $G$ is a $p$-group. I put it to you that your insistence on thinking you need to consider that indicates that, despite your belief that you now “get it”, you are still confused.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Without saying anything further, I'll take some to go over all the definitions and this time try to truly get it. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

What is "maximal" ? In general, let $(U,\le)$ be a partially ordered set. An element $m\in U$ is called maximal if $x\le m$ for all $x\in \{u\in U \mid u\le m \text{ or } m\le u\}$.

In OP, $U=\{H\in 2^G \mid H \text{ is a $p$-subgroup of } G\}$ and for $H,H'\in U$, $H\le H'$ is defined to be $H \subseteq H'$. On one hand, $H'\subseteq H$ since $H$ is maximal. On the other hand, $H\subseteq H'$ according to Theorem 1. As a result, we have $H=H'$.

Remark that $G\notin U$ because $G$ is not a $p$-subgroup of itself if $m>1$. For $m=1$, $|H|=p^n$ implies that $H=G$.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the problem here. There is a convention that when we say that $H$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$, it is convenient to exclude the case $H=G$, on the grounds that, with the normal meaning of maximal, $G$ would be the only maximal subgroup of itself. But when we say that $H$ is a maximal $p$-subgroup of $G$ (or anything similar, like a maximal solvable subgroup of $G$), then we are not excluding the case $H=G$.

Comment: It does not matter  whether the case $H=G$ should be excluded or not. If $H=G$ is excluded, then let $U=\{H\in 2^G\mid H \text{ is a proper subgroup of }G\}$ and everything should go well. The set $U$ is defined according to different contexts.@DerekHolt

Comment: On the contrary, it does matter. If the case $H=G$ is excluded then, according to the definition given, the Sylow $2$-subgroups of a group of order $4$, say, would be its subgroups of order $2$, which is crazy!

Comment: @DerekHolt I just give the argument of "maximality" not the definitions. As you know, in "subgroup", $H=G$ is excluded while in "$p$-subgroup", $H=G$ is not excluded. In different contexts("subgroup" or "$p$-subgroup"), the argument goes well only if $U$ is right defined.  As we can see, the context given in my answer is "$p$-subgroup" and $H=G$ is not excluded.

Answer (score 0):

If $H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup according to your Definition (maximality), then $|H|=p^n$ because such a maximal (in the hypothesis of your Theorem) $p$-subgroup does exist by Sylow's First Theorem.

Comment: This works as an alternative proof, but isn't an answer to this question per se. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since $H'$ is a $p$-group, we can only have $H'=G$ if $G$ is a $p$-group. If $G$ has order that is not a prime-power, then clearly since $H'$ has prime-power order it cannot be equal to $G$.

Here, in contrast to the definition of a "maximal subgroup" which requires that the subgroup be proper, a maximal $p$-subgroup need not be a proper subgroup, so if $G$ is a $p$-group then $G$ is the maximal $p$-subgroup we speak of.

Comment: Agreed, but $G$ might be a $p$-group, so what happens then? The basic problem here is that the OP has misunderstood the meaning of "maximal $p$-subgroup".